# local database synchronization between sql server database and local sql ce database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Im implementing application in which there is local database which uses SQL CE. Each time app starts there has to be synchronization between local database and server database (to have new values in dictionary tables).

Problem is that mappings are different in sql ce and sql server 2008 when using entity framework.

Is it common problem ? is there any way to automate that ?
 Do you know about any good pattern ?

thanks for help,
bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Merge replication, which supports (almost) all SQL Server 2008 datatypes.
Issues relating to EF seem to be unrelated, can you elaborate... You must create the model based on a SQL Compact database, you cannot use a model created against a SQL Server database with a SQL Compact database

Comment: So, there is no possibility to use the same model for both databases ?

Comment: No, you will have to use an modified edmx file (at least)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ADO.Net Synchronization framework? [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx)

Comment: But I want to synchronize only part of tables.

Comment: @potatoMan: Oh, just that? Just point the magic replication gun at them and have at.